# GPS provider not showing current location at first time

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, location

i am trying to get location from both network provider and gps.By using the returned latitude and longitude i am placing markers on map. When i tried with network provider app is working fine.But when i tried to get location from gps, for the **first time it is returning null**. After that it is giving me exact location result. How to get rid from this.?

I think some minor changes i have to made, please suggest me in fixing this.

this is how i am doing this.

```
    public class MapActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {


            private GoogleMap gMap;
            private LocationManager locationManager;
            private String provider;
            boolean gps_enabled = false;
            boolean netwrk_enabled = false;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
                gMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                        .getMap();

    //Focussing india on starting map
                gMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(
                        23.40276491, 77.51953125), 5));

                locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000L, 10F, this);

                gps_enabled = locationManager
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                netwrk_enabled = locationManager
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                if (gps_enabled)
                    provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
                else
                    provider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;

                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

                Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);



    CameraPosition cp = new CameraPosition(new LatLng(
                        location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 14, 40, 90);
                gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cp), 4000,
                        null);
                gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                        new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))
                        .title("I am here"));

                if (location != null) {

                    if (provider == LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "taking from gps",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    else if (provider == LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "taking from network",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    new HttpGetTask().execute();
                }

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPause() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub18d1:d002
                super.onPause();
                locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onResume() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onResume();
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map, menu);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            private class HttpGetTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        //Passing latitude and longitude here to get lat longs from my remote server.
        // using json parsing i am placing multiple markers here.


            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you code is write, But you are not calling LocationManager on starting of Application. Just un comment the following line from your code from your `onCreate()` method.

```
//Location location = locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000L, 10F, this);
```

Uncomment above line and make following change for provider

```
Location location = locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 5000L, 10F, this);
```

Comment: you mean only 

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000L, 10F, this); write.??

because i already initialized location variable know.

Comment: its working fine but only for gps. if i tried to get location from network provider app is crashing.

Comment: see my edited question. i modified like that. is that correct.?

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to Location
This is the error i am getting by doing this.

Comment: @h.APP.y  you have to put that line after this line `provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);` and remove this line 'Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);'

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String, long, float, android.location.LocationListener) the first argument is String then it shoudn't give you that error.

Comment: Location location = locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 5000L, 10F, this); In this line i am getting error as "Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to Location" 
i followed as there in developer site. provider variable is of string type only.

Do i need to write anything in OnLocationChanged().?

Comment: instead of this `Location location = locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 5000L, 10F, this);` write this only `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 5000L, 10F, this);`